# Measuring the process time after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to download a document from a server. Creating the document in the server takes some time, and I need to measure the time it takes from clicking the link to the end of the download process at client side. (or to the beginning of the download?)

Any way for this?

Thanks

Comment: What server side language / technology is used to create the document?

Comment: Just realized and edited the question. I want to measure it at client side, so the server side technology doesn't matter.

Comment: @sahs I have an idea but it would require server side involvement as well, as I can't think of intercepting the end of a file download on client side. It would be important to know what is used on server side.

Comment: Let me start a brainstorming, maybe some of you guys would contribute. Say, we have a hidden iframe. When we click the file's link, we set the href of this iframe to the location of the file and observe changes in readystate attribute of iframe. Does it make sense to you, too? It does to me, but I couldn't implement it in practice. If you encourage me, I'm going to go over it :). Otherwise, I'll give up and try to find some other workaround.

Comment: @sahs this would work for a normal page but I think not for a file download - it won't show up in the iframe, and there is no "ready" state for a file download that I know of. Downloads take place completely outside the normal page context. I really think you need to combine client-side and server-side stuff for this, therefore I'd like to know your platform.

Comment: @Pekka is right, there isn't a ready state on the external document. You have to consider what it is you want to find out. If it's how long it takes to generate the Word Document, you should do that server-side. If it's how long it takes to download, then you should do that client side (Javascript or Browser tools) and expect potentially big differences in results for different PCs, connections, etc. :)

Comment: Ok, let me explain the problem more clearly. (I should have this at the beginning :( )

When the user clicks the link, I want to inform the user that the request is being processed; something like "Please Wait". And when the server side process is completed and the download starts, the "Please Wait" text should be invisible. That's it :).

BTW, I'm using PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your update in the comment:

> When the user clicks the link, I want to inform the user that the request is being processed; something like "Please Wait". And when the server side process is completed and the download starts, the "Please Wait" text should be invisible.

As I said in the comments, this is not as easy to do for a document download as it is for a web page.

A way that would be guaranteed to work is loading the document into an iframe (so that the whole page doesn't freeze), and polling the document's production status from the outside document using Ajax. That could be achieved half-way easily if you can make your document generating PHP script write the production status ("working" / "finished" or even a percentage value) into a text file that the Ajax call can query frequently. You would name the text file by a unique random key that would have to be created in the page containing the download link, and passed to the script generating the document.

You *might* be able, as you say, to query the IFrame's status somehow but I wouldn't know a defined way to do this: There will be no `onload` event (because no document will be loaded - once the browser receives the information to expect a file download, it will pop up the "Save as" dialog and leave the IFrame's context completely). However it *could* be that the IFrame's `src` property is set only when the document is produced (i.e. when the content-type and other headers have been sent) - you would have to try.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Chrome's developer tools to track time. It differentiates between the time taken to connect to the server and the time to download.

To use, Ctrl+Shift+I and then go to the resources tab. Access your page and you should find as you click around, it tells you all the times you might need.

This will tell you from the clients point of view. If you want to know what is taking the server so long to produce the document, you'd need to explore that from your Server-side coding point of view :)